# winforms c++ label text

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Всем привет делаю обычный кликер, есть переменная int score = 0; нужно при нажатии на картинку добавлять к ней единицу, с этим нет проблем. НО ругается на  "`this->score->Text = score;`"

Ошибка:

> E1767 невозможно вызвать функцию "System::Windows::Forms::Label::Text::set" с данным списком аргументов   reaction

и

> C2664 "void System::Windows::Forms::Label::Text::set(System::String ^)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "int" в "System::String ^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this->score->Text = score_green;` преобразуйте в строку `score_green` вызвав метод `ToString()`.

```
this->score->Text = System::Int32(score_green).ToString();
```

Comment: А можете поделится примером как это можно сделать?

Comment: спасибо, ты мне очень сильно помог)

Comment: @SЌĬPクラス: слева от ответа есть 2 кнопки, голосовать за, и отметить как ответ. Не за что.

Comment: На кой ляд используется `System::Int32`? Нельзя просто `score_green.ToString()`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: ну я думаю что там чистый сишный int :) Поэтому и используется